Resizebox and table in springer class
\RequirePackage{booktabs} %for \cline declaration
\documentclass[iicol]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Example Table with Caption at the Top}
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
  \hline
  Data 1 & Data 2 & Data 3 \\
  \hline
  Data 4 & Data 5 & Data 6 \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}

I am trying to include a table using resizebox in a springer document (sn-jnl.cls) with caption at the top but I got multiple errors while compiling among which "Package graphics Error: Division by 0", "Missing \endgroup inserted" or "Missing } inserted". The same code works correctly in various other classes but not the springer one. I observed that if I remove the resizebox or if I put the caption at the bottom of the table, it works correctly. Similarly the problem only appears for the {table} environment, not {table*}.
How can I do to have a table (single column) inside a resizebox with caption at the top in a springer document ?

Note: You should never use \resizebox or \scalebox for tables. The result is always ugly.

Are you sure, that booktabs can be loaded before \documentclass? Only some package do support this and I cannot find anything in the user manual. However, I cannot reproduce the error with the shown code. Tested with TeX Live 2024 and sn-jnl 2019/11/18 v0.1.

I am mostly using \resizebox to resize the height of all table in the same way: \resizebox{!}{0.9\height}{ .
The loading of booktabs before the documentclass was proposed in a tex.stackexchange  discussion due to sn-jnl class wrongly redifining the \cline command.

Scaling tables (and generally text) does also scale the line thickness (aka weight) of fonts and all your vertical and horizontal lines. And it scales the proportions of fonts without hinting. So the fonts become ugly, the weight inconsistent over the document and imbalanced. This is a typographical no-go! Please don't do it! If you want to change the size of a table use another font size, change the distances etc. Everything is better than scaling.

Off-topic: I would also recommend to remove all the vertical lines and most of the horizontal lines and use the \…rule commands of booktabs.

But more relevant is my second comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with the shown code and TeX Live 2023 or 2024 and sn-jnl 2019/11/18 v0.1. (With TeX Live 2022 and older I get an option clash, because the class already loads xcolor without options and xcolor 2.xx does not support loading it several times with different options. So I assume you are also using a more or less up-to-date TeX distribution.)

I am using sn-jnl December 2023 version downloaded from the website of springernature. I use overleaf with pdfLaTeX compiler and Tex Live version 2024.

The "December 2023" version downloaded from https://resource-cms.springernature.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/18782940/data/v11 provides sn-jnl 2019/11/18 v0.1. But as already told with this version and your example I cannot reproduce the issue. Please minimize the preamble of your example, add \listfiles and then show the log file.


How can I ... have a table (single column) inside a resizebox with caption at the top in a springer document ?

Whatever else you do, never ever use \resizebox on tabular-like material.
If your objective is to set the width of the tabular material equal to the width of the text column, I suggest you switch to a tabular* environment and set its target width to \linewidth.
In view of the fact that you appear to be willing to take considerable care to load the booktabs package, I'd also recommend that you (a) employ its line-drawing macros -- such as \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule and, if needed, \cmidrule -- instead of LaTeX's \hline and \cline instructions and (b) get rid of all vertical lines in the table.
The following screenshot contrasts the "looks" of the tables produced by (i) implementing the suggestions made above and (ii) implementing the same suggestions except for applying a \resizebox wrapper to a tabular environment instead of using a tabular* environment as in the first table. I trust you can spot the grossly inconsistent font size that results from employing the \resizebox sledgehammer method.

\documentclass[iicol]{sn-jnl}
%% I've commented out all instructions that aren't needed for this example
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}% ,amsfonts} % 'amssymb' loads 'amsfonts' automatically
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%\usepackage[title]{appendix}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4] % filler text

\begin{table}[ht]

\caption{Example table with caption at the top}

   \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} ccc @{}}
   \toprule
   Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
   \midrule
   Data 1 & Data 2 & Data 3 \\
   Data 4 & Data 5 & Data 6 \\
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabular*}
   
\bigskip
bad: use of \verb+\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{...}+

\smallskip
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
   \begin{tabular}{@{} ccc @{}}
   \toprule
   Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
   \midrule
   Data 1 & Data 2 & Data 3 \\
   Data 4 & Data 5 & Data 6 \\
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2][1-4] % more filler text

\end{document}


Addendum: I compiled the code above on a MacTeX2024 system, with all updates installed thru 7/19/2024.

pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024)

LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2

L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>

Document Class: sn-jnl 2019/11/18 v0.1, which employs

Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n


Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)



The sn-jnl class automatically uses threeparttable in order to make the caption to use the same line width as the tabular it refers to.
This means that the people in charge of the class don't want that the tables are artificially enlarged to the column width (other classes instead do the converse).
Your example code fails because threeparttable cannot work if the tabular is inside a \resizebox command, which is anyway something that should never be done, because it leads to font size inconsistencies.
You could enlarge a table to the column width when the natural size is just a bit short of it. However, this won't work with caged tables (which are ugly to begin with, by the way).
Since you seem to know about booktabs, use it!
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[iicol]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{amsmath}% because sn-jnl needs it
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{Example Table with Caption at the Top}
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
  \toprule
  Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
  \midrule
  Data 1 & Data 2 & Data 3 \\
  Data 4 & Data 5 & Data 6 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2][1-2]

\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{Example Table with Caption at the Top, with some more text}
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
  \toprule
  Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4 \\
  \midrule
  Data 1 & Data 2 & Data 3 & Data X \\
  Data 4 & Data 5 & Data 6 & Data Y \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2][1-3]

\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{Example Table with Caption at the Top, with some more text}
\centering
  \begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cccc@{}}
  \toprule
  Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4 \\
  \midrule
  Data 1 & Data 2 & Data 3 & Data X \\
  Data 4 & Data 5 & Data 6 & Data Y \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2-10]

\end{document}


You see how table 3 is the same as table 2, but enlarged to column width. Personally, I wouldn't.
In any case, don't try and fight the features of a special class meant for submissions to journals or publishers.
